# Mongoose returns an array of values, Does not contain field names, I have over 2W+ documents like this

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this is my document

> I have such data over 2W+, So can't manipulate the array, Thank you, friends

```
  [
    {
      _id: '5dba7ec085e947161cd41ac6',
      name: 'java'
    },
    {
      _id: '5dba7ec085e947161cd41ac7',
      name: 'oracle',
      parent: '1'
    },
    {
      _id: '5dba7ec085e947161cd41ac8',
      name: 'python',
      parent: '1'
    },
    {
      _id: '5dba7ec085e947161cd41ac9',
      name: 'flutter'
    },
  ]
```

this is my code

```
await ctx.model.Sensitive.find({ parent: null }, { name: 1, _id: 0 });
```

this is resault

```
[ { name: 'java' }, { name: 'flutter' } ]
```

My expectations like this

```
[ 'java', 'flutter' ]
```

> I have such data over ***2W+***, So can't manipulate the array, Thank you, friends

Comment: use aggregation

Comment: I'm solved , this is my code ```await ctx.model.Sensitive.distinct('name', { parent: { $ne: null } });```